# Как отправить фото через хероку в бот телеграм?

Tags: python, postgresql, telegram-bot, telebot, heroku

Есть определенные фотографии на пк, нужно сделать так, чтобы они отправлялись в телеграм бот (Бот задеплоин на Heroku).Бот написан на Python. Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать базу данных для отправки фото, но возможно не прав. Объясните пожалуйста как вообще можно "переправить" фото, ну или каким принципом это все делается.

Comment: загрузите свои фотографии на гугл диск к примеру, скопируйте ссылку на их скачивание и передавайте в функцию send_photo  в аргумент photo ссылку

Comment: @MaximChyorny Нерабочий вариант